# Time based Folder Deletion in Logback

Tags: java, slf4j, logback

I was recently struck by a requirement to remove log folders created by logback after a certain period of time.

Say for example,

> if i configure it as 7 days, everyday all log folders older than 7
>   days will be deleted.

It is important to note here that i am already using **timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy** appenders.

An example of my sample configuration is as follows :

```
    <appender name="DC_DEBUG" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">

        <encoder>
            <pattern>[%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS}] [%thread] [%-5level] [%logger : %L] => %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- rollover daily -->
            <fileNamePattern>C:/DataConsolidation/Logs/%d{dd-MM-yyyy}/Debug/Debug.%i.txt</fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>20MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>
```

I am more inclined to use some out of the box solution, but won't hesitate for Custom development..

Any help here ??

Answer (score 1):

You can try TimeBasedRollingPolicy's maxHistory with daily rollover:

http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#tbrpMaxHistory

> The optional maxHistory property controls the maximum number of
>   archive files to keep, deleting older files. For example, if you
>   specify monthly rollover, and set maxHistory to 6, then 6 months worth
>   of archives files will be kept with files older than 6 months deleted.
>   Note as old archived log files are removed, any folders which were
>   created for the purpose of log file archiving will be removed as
>   appropriate.